# How do i call a datatable on partial view mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

How do i call a datatable on partial view mvc.

Here is the partial view:

```
   @model EmailTemplate.UI.Areas.Ticket.Models.AppTicket
<div class="result" id="sss"> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TableAssign">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @*<th>
                        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" id="chkall" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" onclick="Selectallcheckbox()" />
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
                    </th>*@
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Description </th>
                <th> Duedate </th>
                <th> AssignBy</th>
                <th> Status </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @*<tbody>
                @foreach (var itm in Model.TicketList)

                {
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <td>
                            <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" />
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="#">@itm.Title</a>
                        </td>
                        <td> @itm.Description </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            @itm.Duedate
                        </td>
                        <td class="center"> @itm.AssignBy </td>

                        <td>
                            <span class="label label-sm label-warning"> @itm.Status </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>*@
    </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the code:

```
 {
                                debugger;
                                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#TableAssign")) {
                                    $('#TableAssign').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                                }
                                debugger
                                $('#TableAssign').DataTable(); // ERROR: "DataTable() is not a function"
                                var table = $('#TableAssign');
                                //$("#sss").html(data.responseText);
                                debugger
                                $('#TableAssign').DataTable(
                                {
                                    'columnDefs': [{
                                        'targets': 0,
                                        'searchable': false,
                                        'orderable': false,
                                        "bLengthChange": false, "pageLength": 15, "stateSave": true,
                                        'width': '1%',
                                        'className': 'dt-body-center',
                                    }
                                    ,


                                    ],
                                    "language":
                                        {
                                            "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
                                        },
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "serverSide": true,
                                    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                                    "ajax":
                                        {
                                            "url": "/TicketTemplate/GetAssignData",
                                            "type": "POST",
                                            "dataType": "JSON"
                                        },
                                    "columns": [
                                                { "data": "Title" },
                                                { "data": "Description" },
                                                { "data": "Duedate" },
                                                { "data": "AssignBy" },
                                                { "data": "Status" }
                                    ]

                                });

                                //$("#note1").html("");
                                //$("#partialSummaryDiv").html("");
                                //$("#partialSummaryDiv").html(data.responseText);


                                //document.getElementsByClassName('braja')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            }
                        });
```

There is 2 datatable:

For first datatable the Id is TableId.
For TableId it is working very fine but for second partial view the datatable is not initialise or nothing is happening i.e. in this case the controller name is GetAssignData and it is not hit.

if i change the datatable id to TableId it is hit.
Where is the problem???
The condition is sucha way that if :

```
if (obj == 2) {
                            debugger
                            //$.ajax({
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Content("~/TicketTemplate/MyAssign/")',
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                traditional: true,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function (data) {
```

in success data of one controller i will call the above datatable.

so what should i do??

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Remove all your `id` attributes and use class names instead. Its not clear where your script is, but it should not be in the partial. If it is, move the script to your main view or layout.

Comment: how do i use class name

Comment: You already have  a class name on that element - just add another - `class = "table... table-hover tablesssign"` and  then use `$('.tablesssign').DataTable(...` etc. And its not clear from your code, but it also seems like you might be dynamically adding those partials using ajax, so you would need to re-attach the plugin in the success callback

Comment: not working....

Comment: What is not working? (we are not psychic!) And what is your last snippet of code (the ajax call) and how is it related to your other code?

Comment: in first case the js is call..but in the second case the datatable js is not call..i think thats why thats why this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138903/discussion-between-manoj-and-stephen-muecke).